# Changing ownership back and forth

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker, mvt

I'm new to Rust and I'm still struggling with borrowing and move concepts.

To set the context, I'm using a library (namely [MVT](https://github.com/DougLau/mvt) ) that uses following construct to create a layer:

```
    let mut tile = Tile::new(4096);
    let layer = tile.create_layer("First Layer");
    let b = GeomEncoder::new(GeomType::Linestring, Transform::default())
    // ... add some data to b
    let mut feature = layer.into_feature(b);
    feature.set_id(1);
    feature.add_tag_string("key", "value");
    let layer = feature.into_layer();
    tile.add_layer(layer)?;
```

The most interesting pieces are `layer.into_feature(b)` which takes ownership of the layer and later `feature.into_layer()` which returns ownership of the layer again.

This sounds really strange to me. Is this some known concept/design pattern in Rust?
I would expect, that the onwership of layer will remain untouched (i.e. it is not moved but borrowed).

The problem I have with that piece of code is, that I would like to keep a `HashMap` of `Layer`s to avoid creating layers with the same name twice, i.e. sth. like this:

```
let mut layers = HashMap::new();
let layer = layers.entry(layer_name).or_insert(tile.create_layer(layer_name));
```

But this fails with below error, which makes sense b/c `layer.into_feature(b)` is moving the layer out of the `HashMap` which it shouldn't (IMO).

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*layer` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> src/main.rs:39:23
    |
39  |     let mut feature = layer.into_feature(b);
    |                       ^^^^^^---------------
    |                       |     |
    |                       |     `*layer` moved due to this method call
    |                       move occurs because `*layer` has type `Layer`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So to summarize my question:
Is there a way to get the library code working with a hashmap or do I need to change the library to not do that ownership ping-pong?

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty strange, maybe even an antipattern. Even if the `Feature` needs an owned `Layer`, the method names should be more like `new_feature()` and `build_feature()`.

Comment: You can move the layer out of the map temporarily, add the feature then move it back in.

Comment: Thanks @ChayimFriedman. So it's not only my perception that this is weird :-). You are suggesting to use [remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) right? Will try that. You can also put this as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: @Nino, this may be due a requirement of the underlying library or just a bad side effect of an otherwise unnecessary design decision. Reflect on what the abstraction boundary (and the compiler error) is saying: `into_feature()` takes ownership of the `layer` and `into_layer()` gives ownership of `layer`; but nowhere does it say that it actually the *same* `layer`: By having given ownership of `layer`, the `feature` is capable of destructing (or otherwise destroying) the object; `into_layer()` may need to create a new object altogether; that's why you are not allowed to keep references to it

Comment: @user2722968 well "returning ownership of the layer" reads as if it's the same layer. You're right though that the problem might be deeper down.